# Buttons coming while hover over an image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want that when I move my cursor on an image, it should show 3 buttons coming and then when I click on any one of them, a modal should open. I am actually done with this, but the problem is when I click on any of the buttons appearing, a modal is reflected and as soon as I try to close that modal, those three options are shown on that image rather dis-appearing. Please anyone help.

**Here is the code:**

```
<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="caption">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1a" style="color:#000">Add</button>
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1b" style="color:#000">Delete</button>
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1c" style="color:#000">Modify</button>
      </div>
      <img src="Department.png" style="position:fixed" alt="ALT NAME" width="250" height="60">
    </div>
    <h3 class="text" id="D1"><b>Department Options </b></h3> 
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 1a -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1a" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Create Department</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="psw">Department Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Provide a name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="usrname">Department ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrname" placeholder="Provide an ID">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block">Submit
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel
        </button>
        <p>Need <a href="#">help?</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add css too or [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) will be better

Comment: Seeing your custom CSS would be very useful :)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wanna hide those buttons whenever the modal is closed, then its a cakewalk if you use jQuery. You just need to use the **hidden.bs.modal** event of Bootstrap modals in the following way:

```
$('#myModal1a').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

    $('.imgButton').each(function () {

        $(this).hide();

    })

})
```

**Assuming that you provide a class called 'imgButton' to all the buttons** :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, now when I am adding this script to my code, the buttons are disappearing as I close the modal. But, when I hover over the image again, they are not shown again to select anyone of them. What to do??

Comment: Add a function on hover of the image

$('#myImg').hover(function() {
 
 $('.imgButton').each(function () {
 
  $(this).show();
 
 })

})

assuming myImg is the ID of your image

Comment: One problem is occurring in this UI that when I close modal by clicking on the close button in the bottom of the modal and then reopen again, that close button dis-appears sometime. Just b'coz of this I need to refresh my html page to see that close button in footer again. Please suggest how to make that button visible every-time in modal.

Comment: Does the modal footer button also has the class imgButton? remove it if so.

Comment: No, there is no such class in footer button. As i have mentioned above in the code, that only I am using. There is no such class imgButton. What to do??

Comment: can you make a fiddle or link me to your page? it'll be easier for me to debug it